# Capture SAML assertion in TFIM

Tags: saml-2.0, tivoli, tivoli-identity-manager

I want to be able to capture the SAML assertion that is going from IDP to SP in Tivoli Federated Identity manager.
How do I enable trace in Tivoli Federated Identity Manager and capture the SAML assertion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see the SAML assertion value then you can simply add the SAML tracer add-on in Firefox. Its really simple and helpful. Otherwise you can go for below option:

Please put the below for logs and trace in WAS Console:
*=info: com.tivoli.am.fim.*=all

Dont make the changes to configuration tab. It will requires a restart.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21668169